# Visual difference between different charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a question about some charts we are using. We have a page, with +20 the same kind of charts.
We set a width and height so they are better lined up. But we noticed some visual "error". As you can see in the screenshot, the charts have the same height and width. On the first chart, you can see wednesday is very high: 735. On the second chart wednesday has a score of 945. But the 735 of the first chart is visual higher than the 945. Is there something to change this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this it is not just the chart physical width/height. You also need to accommodate the axis scales. To set all to the same scale you need to set the same [`yAxis.min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) and [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) values.

Comment: Thank you. I've been searching for hours now, don't know how i missed that :s